# How to start a permanently running powershell 5.1 script at startup?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a powershell v5.1 script `d:\scripts\script.ps1` that requires powershell to be run with admin permission and the script runs forever, controlling an application that exposes various processes. The script invokes each process in turn then goes back to the first process and so on, forever.

Can `New-JobTrigger` and `Register-ScheduledJob` be used to run `d:\scripts\script.ps1` at startup or do they expect the script to finish at some point?

Comment: you can use task scheduler ,which has an option to run script at startup of system

Comment: it needs to run with admin permissions though. That's why the commands above need to be used I think as they will be run with admin permissions

Comment: It's worth exploring, you can run it as system or different admin account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the Task Scheduler.
Create a new Task, and configure:

**General Page**

1. Set the Task to "Run whether User is logged on or not"
2. Click "Change User or Group..." and add a user with Admin permissions
3. Enable the checkbox "Run with highest privileges"

**Triggers Page**

4. Add a new Trigger, choose Begin the Task "At startup"

**Actions Page**

5. Add a new Action, leave the Action to "Start a program"
6. Set Program/script to "powershell.exe"
7. Set Add arguments (optional) to "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File d:\scripts\script.ps1"

Save, enter credentials for the chosen account, reboot, check that your script is running.

I use this to run a watchdog script on startup that then in turn makes sure other processes (node-based discord chatbots in my case) are running.